# Rspec tests passing when they should be failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing the RoR Tutorial from Michael Hartl.  I am just starting to write some tests, and when I run:

```
 bundle exec rspec spec\requests\static_pages_spec.rb
```

I get no output at all:

```
 C:\Wamp\www\demo_app>bundle exec rspec spec\requests\static_pages_spec.rb
 C:\Wamp\www\demo_app>
```

I've looked around for an answer, I tried changing the version of rspec I'm using to different versions and doing bundle install over again, but I just don't get any output at all from tests that should be failing.

Any ideas what this is about?

Edit: This is what's in my .rspec file:

```
--color
```

And this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5' 
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: Did you run the rspec generator: `rails g rspec:install`?

Comment: Thereafter you should be able to run your specs with `rake spec`.

Comment: The rspec was already installed, but the rake spec command works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I run:

```
rake spec
```

Instead of:

```
bundle exec rspec spec\requests\static_pages_spec.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added `rspec-rails` to **both** `:development` and `:test` environment, as in the example in [Chapter 3 of the tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top):

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end
```

Comment: Yes, my gem file has those three lines exactly.